# Prevent a project from being deleted, allow build configuration changes?

Tags: teamcity

My company has a particular way of working, with an existing CI system, and I'd like to find a way of moving to TeamCity.  I've run into a problem with permissions though.

In our current system, a group of developers might be assigned to project A.  They can add/modify/remove continuous integration tasks that are related to (are children of) project A, but they **can't delete** project A itself.

---

I've got a test install of TeamCity 10, set up with per-project permissions. `Project A` is a top-level project.  There's a `projA` group, which assigns a `dev guy` role with scope limited to `Project A`.  `user A` is a member of the `projA` group.

Whatever permissions I choose for the `dev guy` role, it seems to have one of two outcomes, neither of which is useful:

1. `user A` can't delete `Project A`, but can't create or modify build configurations.
2. `user A` can create and modify build configurations, but can also delete `Project A`.

It looks like `Edit project` is the relevant permission, but it's not granular enough -- it includes some abilities I don't want along with the ones I do.

Is there a way around this?